# Jquery Cookie plugin, check to see if cookie is unset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

So Im using the jquery cookie plugin and I need to check if a cookie is unset. I set it up something like this:

```
if ($.cookie('language')==null) { 


}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any ideas why?

Comment: are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by not working? Have you tried outputting the results of $.cookie('language')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line #90 in the source looks like that SHOULD be the result you want. Check for any errors and test what happens if the cookie is set.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js

Answer (score 0):

Use simply:

```
if($.cookie("language")){}
```

Answer (score 0):

To see what the plugin is returning, do a console.log() call:

```
console.log($.cookie("language"));
```

This should tell you what is being returned from the plugin if you monitor your Inspector / Firebug console.

I think you can get away with just doing if($.cookie("language")) but you'll have to test that.